# Can one use DOM manipulations in Component in angular 2 or it should be done in Directive?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

Can anyone mention the best practices for **DOM** manipulation in Angular 2.
I have researched a lot and couldn't find best solutions.
Should it be done in component itself or create directives?

Comment: The short answer is that you should use the `Renderer2` class to manipulate the DOM. This allows you to run the Angular application using Angular Universal (for server side rendering). If you have no plans for server side rendering, then do as you wish. (i.e. jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular2 api documentation recommends to use data binding properties. If it is still not sufficient to solve your problem, you have to write a directive to access DOM elements and manipulate them. DO NOT MANIPULATE DOM ELEMENTS FROM COMPONENT